# Android app not found on Market

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't been able to find [ROS' android app](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot/Tutorials/AndroidControl#Download_Android_App) in MARKET on my phone (Samsung Sidekick, Firmware: 2.2.1) by doing what's described in the wiki page above (As of now, Nov 15, '11) after searching by "Willow Garage" the result only shows so-called "Science Pro" app. Any tips?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11950/android-app-not-found-on-market/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Scan the QR code at the page from your link: [QR](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android)

Or go to the [Android Market](https://market.android.com/developer?pub=Willow+Garage,+Inc.) and send the applications to your phone. You will have to sign in but you will then be prompted on which device to send the application to.

Hope that helps.

Seth

---

Originally posted by [seth_g](https://answers.ros.org/users/1153/seth_g/) with karma: 178 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-11-15**:
@seth_g thanks. This navigates me to ROS app (However as @ben pointed out, my phone doesn't fulfill the requirement so I can't install the app for now...)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your firmware may be too old. It seems like it requires version 2.3 and up.

---

Originally posted by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) with karma: 674 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on 2011-11-15**:
Click on the 'Android Market' link that Seth posted and then click on anyone of the ROS Apps and on the right sidebar you'll see the minimum requirements.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-11-15**:
@ben thanks. Where can I see that requirement? And the producer of my phone says 2.2 is the latest for my phone, which might mean there's no way for my phone to use ROS app as of today...